# Show that if n divides m where n and m are positive ints greater than 1, then a ≡ b (mod m) implies a ≡ b (mod n) for any positive integers a and b

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Show that if n divides m where n and m are positive integers greater than 1, then
a ≡ b (mod m) implies a ≡ b (mod n) for any positive integers a and b.

I recognise that a similar question has been posted here a year ago, but I really don't understand the answers provided. This is part of my discrete math's assessment, so I kind of need to show my work, and to do so, I got to understand what am doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the definition of $a \equiv b \mod n$? Your question can be answered looking directly at the definitions.

Comment: I don't, but thank's for the hint, I'll try and have a look for it :)

Comment: @HallonSoda Since it's hard to Google for symbols, the search term you're looking for is "equivalence modulo n" or "modular arithmetic".

Comment: This is a special case of *transitivity* of divisibility, i.e. $$ n\mid m\mid k\ \Rightarrow\  n\mid k$$

The OP is simply the special case where $\ k = a-b.\ \ $

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys, I actually get it now (which is surprising) Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

$$a \equiv b \pmod m \iff m \mid a-b \implies n \mid a-b \iff a \equiv b \pmod n$$